# Laravel - Mass assignment || How can I do for updating data if found same unique key, and creating if the data are new

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, mass-assignment

I've created a table named: **staff** in the database.

Inside that table, there are: **id**, **staffID**, **staffName**, **role**, and **password**
which the **id** field is **autoincrement**(its mean primary Key), and the **staffID** is **Unique** Key.

After that, I inserted a few data. For example: **, 69, habie, admin, *123456***

the problem is when i tried to inserting new datas, for example:

| **, 69, habie, admin, *2010201*** | **, 70, rafif, finance, 808080** | **, 71, rizieq, sales, 737373** |

I'll getting an error code, which the error message is:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry
>   '69' for key 'staffID' (SQL: insert into `staff` (`staffID`,
>   `staffName`, `role`, `password`) values (69, Habie, admin, *2010201*))

I've tried many steps for solving this problem. For example:

I used:
*firstOrCreate* Method, *firstOrNew* Method, and *updateOrCreate* Method from *laravel* eloquent class. but it has *no effect*.

```
$this::firstOrCreate([
                        "staffID"               =>$staff["PIN2"],
                        "staffName"             =>$staff["Name"],
                        "role"                  =>$staff["Privilege"],
                        "password"              =>$pass
                    ]);
```

I just want my table is **get update** if the **same key unique has a new password, etc**. And if there are **new datas**, laravel **inserting** that **new data into database**. I hope someone can help me out.

Comment: you have to gave the Primary Key along with the data if it is not found then it will create new record other wise update the record

Comment: How can eloquent understand that it should find the data with your unique key?

Comment: @DhavalPurohit. I've to declare property: protected $primaryKey = "staffID" for explain the primary key in that table.  but still nothing happen. any solution dude? :)

Comment: @DhavalPurohit dunno. maybe with magic method named $primaryKey ? help me please :(

Comment: if you have the staffID unique then why you have used the ID?

Comment: @Gopal Kildoliya given the correct answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you are using `firstOrCreate()` method in wrong way. If `staffID` is unique, you have to use it in the following way.

```
$starff = $this::firstOrCreate([
       "staffID" =>$staff["PIN2"],
  ], 
  [
      "staffName" =>$staff["Name"],
      "role" =>$staff["Privilege"],
  ]);

// Update password
$staff->password = $pass;
$staff->save();
```

This will check fir `staffID` and create a new if don't exists. Then you can update the password or other things details.

Answer (score 0):

firstOrCreate can take two parameters as arrays.
The first array is to search the record to be unique.

try:

```
$this::firstOrCreate([
                        "staffID"               =>$staff["PIN2"]
                     ], [
                        "staffName"             =>$staff["Name"],
                        "role"                  =>$staff["Privilege"],
                        "password"              =>$pass
                    ]);
```

---

Note: this unser is true. But, if we want to update some datas we shall used updatedOrCreate method which the first parameter is the unique key. Thanks bro! :D